# WebRTC Android - Can we record audio of a muted audio track

Tags: android, webrtc, live-streaming, recording

I am trying to record video and audio from webrtc MediaStream - live Streaming. This is working fine, but while trying to mute audio track (either by disabling the stream or setting the volume zero in the receiver side) recorded file also seems to be muted. Are there any options to mute the audio (of any of the peer) while streaming and record with volume?

Comment: native app? web app?

Comment: Android native app.

Comment: I found an old discussion article.
According to this article, it seems difficult.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/fU_me9xr2BY